# How do I fix "the method put(string, string) is undefined for the type string" ? please

Tags: java, string, methods, put

```
 package Utils; 

 import java.util.HashMap; 

 import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

 public class KitApi {

     public static HashMap<String, String> kit = new HashMap<>(); 

     public static void setKit(Player p, String kit) {
         kit.put(p.getName(), kit);
     }

     public static String getKit(Player p) {
         if (kit.containsKey(p.getName())) {
             return kit.get(p.getName());
         } else {         
             return "nenhum";
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the map or the parameter. The parameter `kit` shadows the map's name.
For example:

```
 public static void setKit(Player p, String _kit) {
    kit.put(p.getName(), _kit);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `this` keyword to differentiate between your kit instance and your kit parameter:

```
public static void setKit(Player p, String kit) {
    this.kit.put(p.getName(), kit);
}
```

For instance, when IDEs generate getters/setters, you will see that setters method are:

```
public void setXxx(Integer xxx) { 
    this.xxx = xxx; 
}
```

The usage of `this` is exactly to distinguish between class objects and method parameters.

Check more details in its documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html